# Building a LSTM Cell using Keras

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to build a RNN for text generation. I'm stuck at building my LSTM cell. The data is shaped like this- X is the input sparse matrix of dim(90809,2700) and Y is the output matrix of dimension(90809,27). The following is my code for defining the LSTM Cell-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

My understanding is that the input_shape should be the dimension of the input matrix, and the dense layer should be the size of the output for each observation, i.e 27 in this case. However, I get the following error-

```
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (90809, 2700)
```

I'm not able to figure out what is going wrong. Can anyone please help me figure out why is the lstm_input expecting 3 dimensions?

I tried the following as well-

```
X= np.reshape(np.asarray(dataX), (n_patterns, n_vocab*seq_length,1))
Y=np.reshape(np.asarray(dataY), (n_patterns, n_vocab,1))
```

This gave me the following error-

```
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_7 to have shape (None, 90809, 2700) but got array with shape (90809, 2700, 1)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about the difference between `input_shape`, `batch_input_shape` and `input_dim` [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape).

For `input_shape`, we don't need to define the `batch_size`. This is how your LSTM layer should look like.

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X.shape[1], 1)))
```

or

```
model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)))
```